# MP3 File Takes Over Program

Tags: android, mp3

I'm building a simple button app which plays an mp3 player file while changing the backround color and image.  The problem is, once the file starts playing the audio clip, nothing else can be done.  I can't even change the volume of the audio until after the clip has finished.  Any tips on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            current_image++;
            current_image=current_image%images.length;
            imgview.setImageResource(images[current_image]);
            appMP.start();

            {
                try {
                  Thread.sleep(7500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });


}
```

}

Comment: what is the point of `Thread.sleep(7500)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not sleep on the main thread.  Ever. It causes the app to stop responding to UI events and redrawing, because the main thread never returns to the looper to process messages. That's what's causing all your problems.  Remove it and you'll be fine.  If you need to do something when it finishes, use an OnCompletionListener.